# Create aspnetdb roles & assign them to users in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, aspnetdb

I have created FBA application with following method

http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/

I also have created create user page in visual studio. It is working fine. I am also able to login with created users.

But all my created users getting rights of contribute.

I have created roles using Donal's method, but i am not using them.

So can anyone tell me how can i create new roles & assign them to created users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [FBA User Management Tool for SharePoint 2010](http://fbamanagementtool.codeplex.com/) on codeplex earlier in the week.  I have not had a chance to play with it, maybe it will help you out.